# how to update a listbox from a web method?

Tags: c#, jquery, listbox, webmethod, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to update a listbox on the basis of the items selected on another listbox.
For listboxes I am using bootstrap-multiselect, therefore I can't use OnSelectedIndexChanged event.So for that I have called  a web method on DropDownHide event of multiselect.

JS

```
 <script>
 $(function () {
        $('[id*=listbox1]').multiselect({
            maxHeight: 150,
            enableFiltering: true,
            onDropdownHide: function (event) {
                var selected = $('[id*=ListBox1]').val();    
                PageMethods.ListBox1OnSelectedIndexChanged(selected);        //call server side function on selected index changed
            }
        });            
    });
</script>
```

Code Behind

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static void lbfSupplierOnChange(string[] data)
    {
        //here I want to access ListBox2 like this

        ListBox2.DataTextField = "FactoryName";
        ListBox2.DataValueField = "pkFactoryId";
        ListBox2.DataBind();
    }
```

Error

```
An Object Reference is required for the non static field,method
```

Now I think I have to use jquery AJAX, but I am confused about how to send a sql data object and set ListBox2.DataTextField.

Comment: What sql data object? Why not send 'FactoryName' and 'pkFactoryId' back to client form the WebMethod and set it on the UI side?

Comment: You can't bind asp.net elements to a web method attribute since the scope of those elements is outside. You need to return a list from your webmethod and then create/bind them in your js.

Comment: Thanks vabii and DinoMyte actually I dont have idea about how can I send  an iqueryable data and access it in UI.